# foreign key not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, has-many, polymorphic-associations

I'm developing an app for college where a user can log on & upload details of a hiking trail.

So far everything is working & I have also implemented a nested form for photos in each hiking trail.  A user can log-on & create a hike.

I would like to display all the hikes which the user created in there show/profile page but when I've set up the relationships in my database & the `has_many` & `belongs_to` options in my model. I've also tried to do this with nested `accepts_nested_attributes_for :hikingtrails` it does none of this works.

I've checked my database when a hikingtrail is created by a user it is not updating the user_id field in the table.

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this entirely the wrong way, should I be looking at polymorphic associations?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :photos_attributes,  :hikingtrails_attributes


  has_many :hikingtrails
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hikingtrails, :allow_destroy => :true, :reject_if => :all_blank




class Hikingtrail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description,  :name, :looped, :photos_attributes,:directions_attributes, :user_id


    has_many :photos
    has_many :trails
    has_many :directions
    belongs_to :user
```

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Your Profile</h1>
</div>


<p>
  <b>username:</b>
  <%= @user.user_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>email:</b>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>

<h4>Small Photos</h4>
<% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
<%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
<% end %>

<h4>Hiking Trails</h4>
<% @user.hikingtrails.each do |hk| %>
<%= hk.name %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Edit your Profile", edit_user_path(current_user), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add `:user_id` to your accessible attributes in the Hikingtrail model. Try the following:

```
attr_accessible :description, 
                                  :duration_hours, 
                                  :duration_mins, 
                                  :name, 
                                  :looped,
                                  :addr_1,
                                  :addr_2,
                                  :addr_3,
                                  :country,
                                  :latitude,
                                  :longitude,
                                  :photos_attributes,
                                  :trails_attributes,
                                  :directions_attributes,
                                  :user_id
```

**UPDATE**:
After seeing the form code, I think it's probably not necessary to do the above and could potentially also be unsafe. Instead, don't set the user_id through mass assignment, but handle user assignment in your controller like so:

```
class HikingtrailsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @hikingtrail = Hikingtrail.new(params[:hikingtrail])
    @hikingtrail.user = current_user
    if @hikingtrail.save
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: good point, but it still doesn't work & is throwing back not errors, when I check the database user_id has not been updated

Comment: Okay, could you update your question with a copy of the form?

Comment: I thought you wanted to send nested attributes for the `hikingtrail` on the user, which would mean you'd make the current user the main object for your form and add `fields_for :hikingtrails` in your form. If you don't do that, you can lose the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :hikingtrails` from your User model and simply set the `user_id` in the create action of your controller. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you Jaap, that worked.  I wonder why it didn't work with the `has_many` & `belongs_to` as it has worked for me before.  Also why is it `@hikingtrail.user = current_user` rather than `@hikingtrail.user_id = current_user`

Comment: Because @hikingtrail.user_id expects an Integer while current_user is a User object. You could do `@hikingtrail.user_id = current_user.id` though.